# My executable doesn't start in Windows. How to debug failed DLL loading?

Tags: c++, windbg, mingw-w64

i am have been trying for last week to compile my linux code to windows env , after all my code was compiled ,its been failing to start my executables since it failed on loading my dll it self .

my project is composed of 1 executable called ( pcie_logger) and 1 dll (libpci_test.dll) which are linked to few static libraries in windows , the dll is being loaded dynamically only in startup .

**PcieLogger.cpp:**

```
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
LIB_TRACK2(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
PcieLogger tool;
printf("Hello World\n");
return PciTest::main(tool, argc, argv);
}
```

**PcieLogger.h:**

```
#include "PciTest.h"

class PcieLogger: public PciTool {
public:
PcieLogger(): PciTool(){}
virtual ~PcieLogger() = default;
virtual u_int32_t   AddParserParams() override;
u_int32_t           Run() override;
};
```

**PciTest.cpp:**

```
 #ifdef _WIN32
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule,
                   DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                   )
 {
printf("PciTest::DllMain\n");
switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    break;

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    // DisconnectFromDriver();
    break;

case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
}
return TRUE;
}

#endif


int PciTest::main(PciTest& test, int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("PciTest::main\n");
    testInstance = &test;
    int status = 0;
try {
    status = status || test.AddParserParams();
    status = status || test.ParseArgs(argc, argv);
    status = status || test.InitResources(argv[0]);
    status = status || test.Run();
} catch (exception& e) {
    test.mainExceptionTagsHandle(e.what());
    status = 1;
}
test.handleTestFinish(status);
return status;
}
```

**When i'm trying to run windbg on my executable i'm getting the following:**

```
(558.20fc): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for 
z:\compiled\libpci_test.dll - 
libpci_test!ZN7PciTest4mainERS_iPPc+0x3c53b:
00000000`00f6592b 64488b042500000000 mov   rax,qword ptr fs:[0] 
fs:00000000`00000000=????????????????
0:000>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you DLL failed to load, it looks like it crashed in `PciTest::main`.

Comment: i have added printf in the function main , why i cannot see it ?

Comment: `printf` output is buffered, if you want to see the output of a `printf` immediately add `fflush(stdout);` afterwards. Also as an experiment I would try removing all the code from `PciTest::main` (except the printf) and see what happens then.

Comment: Take the `printf` out of `DllMain`.  There are restrictions on what you can do in a `DllMain` function, and I don't think `printf` is anywhere close to safe to call.

Comment: @john , i have added fflush function after each printf , it still doesnot print anything and crashed at the same place .

Comment: sxe ld:YOURDLLNAMEHERE ; on break .reload /f ; bu some function that you are interested in ; g

Comment: @blabb i am not sure how this help me find out whats is broken , i have added printf in the begin on my exe & main function and  nothing is  printed out .

Comment: @ibrahims Did you try removing everything from `PciTest::main`? If you do that and your program no longer crashes then the problem is in the removed code. If it still crashes then you have another problem. One thing you haven't mentioned is how you are exporting your methods from the DLL, that's kind of important, and maybe you made a mistake there.

Comment: you have tagged it windbg and i have commented how to break on your dll load apart from that i dont have the slightest idea what your code does

Comment: @ibrahims The assembly shows that you are trying to deference a null value. Set up your symbols. (If you don't know how, start with .symfix .) If the DLL is yours, be sure to load have the PDB available. If you have the code, often this will be enough to open a code window highlighting the problem line. Dump the stack. (=k)

Comment: i have managed to fix the issue , i started by taking small program which only print hello world , seems like the flags i added in my cmake is causing issues , so i started to remove flag by flag and now its running perfect , thank you all